AMP-Youtube not rendering sometimes until page is force-reload
I'm using AMP-Youtube to integrate videos on my website, and it works like a charm most of the time.
For some reason, sometimes the videos don't show up at all; when it happens, no video on the page is displayed. I've found that deleting cookies and forcing reload helped, but I don't want that behavior on my users.
I haven't found repeatable repro steps for this bug and it's driving me crazy!
Any ideas of what could be the issue? My website is thelibraryofsonorities.com if that helps.
I'm using AMP HTML – Version 2404021934000, with an integration that looks like this
<amp-youtube style="border-radius:10px" layout="responsive" width="560" height="315" data-videoid="Fy3JxUfE9ds" data-param-start="102"></amp-youtube>

And here's what it looks like when the bug happens, no specific errors show up in the console.

Thank you very much for you help!

Do you have the YT-Video in the view point?
Put the VT-Video out of the view point and try again.

Il not sure what you mean by in / out the view point?

It means, that the video shall may be not above the fold from the screen. So it will be loaded if you scroll down and bring the video in the view point. Try 600 px down from the top of the page. (that rule comes from the iframe tag)
